# Version-specific programming language tags (python vs. python3)

Tags: discussion, tags

Until recently, the tag [python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) was the only tag for the [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) programming language. Now there’s also a [python3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3) tag:

1. OP tagged [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/16246/60) with [python3](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python3) (new tag, only used in this question).
2. I [retagged](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/revisions/16246/5) the question with [python](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) (used in 45 questions), edit-commenting: "no need for a "python3" tag (can be specified in the question)".
3. OP ([accidentally](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/version-specific-programming-language-tags-python-vs-python3?noredirect=1#comment3528_1047)) [retagged](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/revisions/16246/7) it again.

**Do we want to have version-specific programming language tags?**

Comment: Oops, sorry, @Unor. I am the OP. I was adding another tag, things got mixed up, and I must have accidentally deleted your tag & replaced. Sounds a bit like "the dog ate my homework", I know, but it's true. I didn't intentionally change it back.

Comment: @Mawg: No problem :) Maybe we’ll decide here that we want such version-specific tags, so it’s good that this came up (better sooner than later).

Comment: @Mawg hey, the dog *did* eat my homework! Um... I suppose it's better then spilling the soup on my homework...

Comment: @unor well.. shouldn't the question reflect the fact-by-accident nature of the retag? Story of a "notorious vicious OP" vs a "whooops... OP"...

Comment: @naxa: Aye, I referenced the comment.

Answer (score 8):

**No.** We had a similar issue over at Android.SE (with CyanogenMod and version specific tags) and decided they are only leading to clutter. If the question is specific to a version, that should be stated explicitly in the question text.

While on some SE sites "versioned tags" serve a good purpose (at Android.SE we e.g. have those for different Android versions), which those are is pretty much site-specific. On SR I see a good use for tags like [windows-8](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-8) which affect a much wider range of users, and help sorting things out – but not for every single programming language or software. Otherwise we'd end up with specific version tags for e.g. [firefox](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefox), just because a user wants some addon to be compatible with the version he's just using – and similar things.

Comment: It's not as simple as that - there are major language differences between Python 2 & 3, with PRINT being the worst to handle. Python 2 PRINTs break in Python 3 and the script won't run. I think that that alone justifies a separate tag, at least on S.O. For s/w recommendations, I will let you guys decide.

Comment: This from a Python3 interpreter. First the new PYthin3 form, then the old PYthon2 form.
`>>> print("hello")  
hello  
>>> print "hello"  
SyntaxError: invalid syntax  
>>>`

Comment: @Mawg I know that. This was a big headache for me with several of my Python projects. So I agree with you for SO. For SR I only agree it's a valid *requirement* – but that doesn't make it a valid *tag* IMHO.

Comment: Fine by me. @unor was looking for a ruling & you have given one. Thanks for clarifying. Btw, maybe you can help answer my question which started this? (there's even a bonus)       ;-)

Comment: Glad we can agree on that :) As for the "starter": My IDE is named `vi`, you won't be happy with that. I don't use GUIs for programming – neither with Python nor with PHP or Bash. All done in a simple text editor (well, to tell truth: not `vi`, but `mcedit` – the built-in editor of *Midnight Commander*). Felt no need yet to try any IDE, though I of course see the advantages.

Comment: ah I want to downvote so much. I am a bit ashamed but also proud. I trust your wisdom Izzy. It's just with python3, isn't it all just lead to more confusion if you try to cover both? I mean, cyanogenmod may have countless versions, but python really has only two of them, and they are reasonably incompatible...

Comment: @naxa See my comment on [your answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/1049/185). We don't even have a `cyanogenmod` tag here, but we have a `python` tag. I could count that a question for removal ;) I still stick to my opinion: if it's important, point it out in the question text.

Answer (score 2):

Izzy may generally be right to have 1 tag... but specifically with Python and Python3, 2 tags are better:

- **only two** versions of pythons exist in general use, 2 and 3 - not endless of them
- they are reasonably incompatible

Let's imagine if I or you  were to ask a python question...

- someone who asks a python question is either a beginner or already knows if s/he wants 2 or 3
- (extra benefit) beginners would notice "hey there are 2 versions" when tagging - opportunity to learn
- if someone is looking for python3 specifically, s/he'll be unhappy with something that only works in 2

So, I think, two tags is the best. `[python]` and `[python3]`.

- now when specifically *need* python3 support you could filter to `[python3]`
- when it doesn't matter you can choose `[python]`, standing as "default"

Comment: So say next year comes Python 4, and has the same issues. You then ask for the next tag? There are currently less than 50 questions tagged `python`. I might re-think the issue if there were 500, of which it would make a difference for at least 100. But not for one or two. And your imaginery beginner should, as everyone else, make it clear in the question body: if (s)he doesn't know whether to ask for v2 or v3, what tag to use then? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Izzy cyanogenmod is about android. It comes every so often. Google wants a market to sell to... In the last almost 25 years python had 3 versions. How old is softwarerecs.SE? I do not expect py4 to appear any time soon.

Comment: I know CM (using it myself on multiple devices; see my profile ;) Still, I hold up my arguments. But I am one, you are one – we two alone are not to decide. Your answer is new, so it would be unfair to compare votes right now. Let's check back in a week on that. But as downvotes count in as well, it looks like most voters (up to now) agree with me.

Comment: @Izzy if the imaginary beginner doesn't know which to use, maybe it's because s/he doesn't know multiple ones exist. The tags would tell that story... And as I imagine it, it's not `v2` or `v3`, but rather `python` or `v3` (python3, that is), because 2 is the default, and I expect it to always be, since the narrative goes down as "python or python3000", so the tradition will always address it as "python3" even when it will be the new default, until python2 disappears, if ever. In which latter, far-away case the tag could be renamed to `python2` retrospectively.

Comment: That's not what tags are for, sorry.

Comment: @Izzy meta: oh I do know you know CM, sorry. :D Never questioned that. I am just formulating the point, it was prone to be misunderstood unfortunately... I know you **do** know CM, you used to help me a lot.

Comment: Thought so, forgot the smiley – sorry ;)

Comment: @Izzy I guess you mean tags are not for spreading the word of multiple python versions, not a teaching material - I tend to disagree personally but hey, and you're right they have more important roles to stand for probably... Anyway I was just saying they do not harm, they just do this extra little gain here... The main reason is to be able to filter. Python3 compatibility is something that is *not* granted for "python compatibility"... anyone looking for py3 specifically wont be happy with "woo hey it's py2 only", choose [python3]. And when looking for "py2 and/or py3", s/he choose [python]

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/tagging *you should avoid creating new tags if possible […] you should only create new tags when you feel you can make a strong case that your question covers a new topic that nobody else has asked about before on this site* (just as a short excerpt).

Comment: Isn't the case "[python] hey IAM NOT INRESTDE IN PTTHON 2!!!!!" del del "[python] I am looking for python3 *specifically*... problem problem" -> "[python3] problem problem" strong enough? Anyway, the idea is here to vote for now. Curious about the one week later! ;)

Comment: @naxa So, your point is that python2 and python3 are so enormously different that solutions to one will significantly often not apply to the other? And that because of this we should make an exception to the rule that we don't want versions in the tag? Did I get this right?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs anyone interested in python *3* will *not* be interested in python2 at the time the search takes place for *3*. anyone interested in "python" wishes to see either python-default-2 or python3 results but not both, at the particular search-time. the only practical exception I can think of is when someone is looking for compatibility, and then both can be specified (or some tag like "version compatibility")

Comment: @naxa Okay, so the main point is that Python 2 vs Python 3 are special and differ from other languages (e.G. Java1.2 vs Java8) that they are basically two different languages and thus merit their own tag each?