# Make [html5] a synonym for [html]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I noticed that, next to [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html), we also have a [html5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) tag now.

I think we don’t need version-specific tags for HTML.

(Related discussion: [Version-specific programming language tags (python vs. python3)](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1047/60))

If we agree, these could be retagged manually (currently only used on 10 questions), but I think it would be appropriate to add it as synonym. I can’t propose [html5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) as synonym for [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) though:

> Failed to propose synonym:
>
> Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators

Comment: Agree, this only adds clutter and confusion here. I'll do this when we get a little more support, and if no one has any objections.

Comment: @Undo full ack from my end – following the reasoning given by [Toms answer](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/2501/185).

Comment: @Undo So shall we go ahead? There seems to be no opposition :)

Comment: Done, thanks for the reminder @Izzy

Comment: Anytime, @Undo – so I've marked it `status-completed`, right? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merged [html5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) into [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) and created a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

I do agree as it does add unnecessary confusion. I think if questions require version specific HTML, it can add that as a requirement in the body of the question. I think we should migrate all [html5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) tags to just [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html) and add [html5](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html5) as a synonym of [html](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/html).